# Binary data in MySQL

Tags: mysql, binary

I need to store binary data, such as `1110000`, in MySQL.  When I select it, I need the return value to be the same `1110000` again.

What data type should I use?  Can I use bit?  Or would varbinary be better?

Comment: Is the number of bits bounded? (is the maximum length of the binary string known, in other words).

Comment: no, it isn't.. the number of bits that i want to store is vary.

Comment: I don't know your use case, but if you absolutely have to get 00011 back from 00011 you could insert a 1 in front of all cases, then remove the leading 1 so you insert 100011 and get out 100011

Comment: By saying "when I select it", do you really mean just selecting the field or do you allow some conversations in the query? And what about client (app) side conversion? The best way would be to store the value as a BLOB field and convert it from/to a bit array in your app.

Answer (score 10):

When you're dealing with binary numbers you can use a [bit field](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/bit-field-values.html), e.g.:

```
bit(64)
```

is a bit field with up to 64 significant bits (the maximum size allowed).

In order to insert constant values, you can use the b'value' notation like so:

```
insert into bits values (b'0001001101001');
```

You can convert a bit field to a number by just adding 0 or using cast(). There's also the handy bin(), hex(), and oct() function to print the value in a particular base.

If non-numeric, varbinary or blob would be the most efficient storage method, binary is also available (it will pad shorter values with nil bytes tho).

In case, you don't want to deal with the conversions, you can store the string in a varchar or char. It will only use up about 8 times the space of a compact varbinary.

To insert/read from your app, you'll need to convert your sequence into a packed byte array, then store the packed string in the varbinary column. In C# you might use BitConverter, for php you might use pack/unpack.

Comment: i've tried to do:
INSERT INTO `db_test`.`t_bits` (`val`)
VALUES (b '0001001101001');

and then:
SELECT val+0 FROM `t_bits` it returns 617
SELECT cast(val as unsigned) FROM `t_bits` also returns 617
SELECT cast(val as binary) FROM `t_bits` it returns 'i'
SELECT bin(val) FROM `t_bits` it returns '1001101001'

the return value that i want is same as value that has been inserted. '0001001101001'

and how to do that in blob? i dont undestand.

i'm very confused.. thx so much..

Comment: leading 0's aren't significant in a numeric value so 0001001101001 is read as 1001101001 which is 617. for non-numerical. the easiest is to store it in a varchar or char

Comment: i need data type that requires smallest storage.. 

if so, i would rather use varbinary, right? because, based on mysql manual, storage requirement for varchar and varbinary is the same..

is there no other way with bit data type? i'm still curious.

can u explain how to store binary string (not image) using blob? 

thx for your answers, jspcal.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Hope, this code can help you:

---

**for select:**

```
     select conv(column_name, from_base, to_base) from table_name
     //example:
     select conv(column1, 10, 2) from table1;
```

**for insert:**

```
     insert into table_name(column1) values( B'binary_data') ;
     //example : 
     insert into table1(column1) values( B'1110000');
```

**for query:**

```
    select column1,column2 from table_name where column1 & B('binary_data');
    //example: 
    select column1, column2 from table1 where column1 & B('1110000');
```