# Mysql - Split a number into separate columns and then sum it by each separate columns

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this below:

```
id        name         data
~~        ~~~~         ~~~~
1         Crank        10111010
2         Test1        01010101
3         Test2        01110000
4         Bats         11101010
5         Cat          00011000
```

I'm trying to split the numbers from the data column into separate numbers and sum all of them. In this case, if I sum it all, it should give me results like below...

```
  10111010
+ 01010101
+ 01110000
+ 11101010
+ 00011000
= 23343121
```

I could sum it without separating the numbers if the data is small, but if i have few thousands of rows, the result is not what I want.

I want to achieve this by using just Mysql functions.

Comment: What happens if a given column sum exceeds 10?  Does the excess rollover to the previous column, or would it just be dropped?

Comment: (or does it just never happen)

Comment: You basically need: `SELECT SUM(CAST(data AS BIGINT)) FROM your_table_name`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the number can exceeds 10, it wont roll over..... for example... the results can be 27 87 10 5 67 109 89 3.... (8 columns)

Comment: Do we know the length of the data before hand? and will it be same always?

Comment: @Sameer it will always be 8 columns... but only consists of 1s and 0s... like this, 10110101

Comment: This doesn't look like optimal table design to me.  I suggest maintaining separate columns for each "bit" value (or maybe even just having a single column).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen do u mean use this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032239/binary-data-in-mysql#comment1956324_2032258

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select id, name, concat(s1,' ',s2,' ',s3,' ',s4,' ',s5,' ',s6,' ',s7,' ',s8) as data from (
SELECT id, name,
SUM(SUBSTRING(data,1,1)) s1, 
SUM(SUBSTRING(data,2,1)) s2, 
SUM(SUBSTRING(data,3,1)) s3, 
SUM(SUBSTRING(data,4,1)) s4, 
SUM(SUBSTRING(data,5,1)) s5, 
SUM(SUBSTRING(data,6,1)) s6, 
SUM(SUBSTRING(data,7,1)) s7, 
SUM(SUBSTRING(data,8,1)) s8 FROM your_table_name) as sums
```

Added space for each sum
Hope this helps

Comment: how do you differentiate the sums? do you want space as separator?

Comment: actually, i need to separate as different column when i return the results in my table view... will need to check the results first.. cuz i might need to store it as binary numbers as well..a change of plan. However, your answer does give me some ideas. Thanks.